# Get taxonomy name as Wordpress page title

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, page-title

I am trying to save the selected taxonomy as a part of a page title. I'm fairly new to coding (1 month ago) so basically, my head is about to explode right now. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks for you help.

```
            // CRED SAVE DATA HOOK
            add_action('cred_save_data', 'my_save_data_action',10,2);
            function my_save_data_action($post_id, $form_data)
            {
                // if a specific form
                if ($form_data['id']==9) 
                {
                    {
                    if (isset($_POST["property-new-name"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['property-new-name'];
                        $taxonomy = 'property-name';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["route"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['route'];
                        $taxonomy = 'street';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["township"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['township'];
                        $taxonomy = 'township';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["locality"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['locality'];
                        $taxonomy = 'city';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["postal_code"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['postal_code'];
                        $taxonomy = 'postal-code';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["administrative_area_level_1"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['administrative_area_level_1'];
                        $taxonomy = 'state';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["country"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['country'];
                        $taxonomy = 'country';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["country_short"])) 
                    {
                        $terms = $_POST['country_short'];
                        $taxonomy = 'country-code';
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }


                    {

                        $taxonomy = 'property-name';
                        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "names"));
                        $term = $term_list[0]; // getting first term, if there are multiple terms
                        $proname = $term;

                        $contract = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "wpcf-contract", true );
                        $title = $proname ." for " . $contract . " " . $_POST["township"]; 
                        // Update the post into the database
                        $my_post = array(
                            'ID'           => $post_id,
                            'post_title' => $title
                        );
                        $my_post['post_status'] = $_REQUEST['post_status'];
                        wp_update_post( $my_post ); 
                 } 
             }

            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Here is the code:

```
        $list = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'property-name', array("fields" => "names"));
        $proname = $list[0];
```

Thanks @chiragswadia

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. Check below

```
    $taxonomy = 'pro-name';
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "names"));
    $term = $term_list[0]; // getting first term, if there are multiple terms
    $proname = $term

    $contract = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "wpcf-contract", true );

    $title = $proname ." for " . $contract . " " . $_POST["town"]; 
    // Update the post into the database
    $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $title
    );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Sadly no, it didnt work. I have also added the ; for line 4 ($proname = $term;) but still there is an error. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @AnilAstrio Check whether `$post_id` exists before you are using it in `$my_post` array! Also if you can paste the whole code snippet, it will be easy to debug.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I just updated the code. Appreciate it very much

Comment: Why have you wrapped the `wp_update_post` code block inside `{ }` blocks. I do not see any else condition as well. I also see that you have put one empty { inside the if block!